# how to get acces to repository from a listener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, repository

I would like to make a request to a database from a subscriber

From a repository: it 's easy I use the following (for exemple entity user where I want to retrieve user with id=1 .

```
 $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager->getRepository('NameBundle:User');
 $user = $repository->find(1);
```

But how can I do the it from a suscriber.

Here what I tried... (without sucess as I got the following from Symfony2: "FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Sdz\BlogBundle\Form\EventListener\Subscriber::getEntityManager()"

```
namespace Sdz\BlogBundle\Form\EventListener;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class TraductionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
  public static function getSubscribedEvents()
  {
    return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData');
  }


  public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
  {
    $form = $event->getForm();      
    $datas = $event->getData(); 

    $userexist == 'no'

    foreach ($datas as $data){
        if ($data->getUser()->getId() == 1)     { $userexist = 'yes'; $user= $data->getUser();  }
    } 

    if ($userexist == 'no') {
        $repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('SdzBlogBundle:User');
        $user = $repository->find(1);
    }   

    $form
    ->add('notes', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new NoteType,
                    'label' => $user->getName(),
                    'required' => false,
                    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your class isn't extending Subscriber and so getEntityManager isn't defined.  Maybe I'm misreading something?

Comment: @DaOgre my class implement EventSubsriberInterface. Is it what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it to constructor (if it's not a service):

```
class TraductionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
  private $em;

  public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
  {
      $this->em = $em;
  }

  ...
```

and use:

```
new TraductionSubscriber($em);
```

Comment: I got the following message when adding the construct function to my class: "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Sdz\BlogBundle\Form\EventListener\TraductionSubscriber::__construct() must be an instance of Sdz\BlogBundle\Form\EventListener\EntityManagerInterface, none given,"

Comment: @Aleqxs you need to get EM instance before passing it. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976226/symfony2-how-call-the-repository-of-an-entity-in-the-formtype/26976628#26976628)

Comment: @Aleqxs Ah, I forgot to ask, where are you calling it? in controller or in formType?

Comment: @Aleqxs also `Sdz\BlogBundle\Form\EventListener\EntityManagerInterface` is very strange..

Comment: I am calling it from a FormType (that form type use ->addEventSubscriber.

Comment: why is EntityManagerInterface very strange? actually Symfony Fatal Error does take the name of the class used to define $em in the construct function you gave me => public function __conctruct(EntityManagerInterface $em)

Comment: @Aleqxs really? Shouldn't it be `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface`?

Comment: well right, if I write use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface then YES INDEED it says "Sdz\BlogBundle\Form\EventListener\TraductionSubscriber::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface, none given, called in ..." But I still have this error.. how can I solve it?

Comment: @Aleqxs did you read my above comment? You have to get the instance of EM (in controller for ex.) -> pass it to FormType -> pass it to the `TraductionSubscriber`.. Or declare the FormType as a service and inject the EM.

Comment: OK haven't understood that so far. so how do I get the instance of EM in controller? then I have to pass it to FormType? (but how) (sorry I am a begginner at Symfony)

Comment: @Aleqxs Ok, I created a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9633890aa3b1c856a634)

Comment: ok I try to do the same but got following error: The required option "em" is missing. (actually my controller "call" a form (translationsType.php) which itself call an other form (translationType.php) which call the subscriber (subscriber.php). I guess at one point the em options is missing...

Comment: Do you think that if I convert my subsriber in a service that would be easier to use then doctrine?

Comment: @Aleqxs You better [declare your form as a serice](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=symfony2+form+as+a+service), inject EM service, pass that em to the subscriber.

Answer (score -1):

You can get Doctrine object via container.

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

[...]

$this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
```