# Symfony2: How to Call functions in Repository class from Type

Tags: php, symfony, repository

I'm new in symfony2 ver 2.7:
I would like to create registration number in form with data from count rows in existing table.

It's OK when i create in PatientController and show the result in twig format.
But i need show the result in text type form. I write in PatientRepository a function:

```
public function getNumberPatient()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('name')
        ->select('COUNT(name)');
    return (int)$qb->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

And in my Entity file to generate like this:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('dateBirth', 'date', array(
            'years' => range(date('Y'), date('Y', strtotime('-50 years'))),
            'required' => TRUE,
        ))
        ->add('regCode', 'text', array(
            'required' => TRUE,
            'data' => function(PatientRepository $r){
                    return $r->getNumberPatient();
                },
```

I have a trouble when i call this function from PatientEntity. Is it Possible?

I did create function with:

```
'query_builder' => function(PatientRepository $r){
                    return $r->getNumberPatient();
```

but it give an error

```
The option "query_builder" does not exist. Defined options are: "action",
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it:

- You can get the data in controller, then pass it to form, like this:

example in controller:

```
public function someAction()
{
    $data = $em->getRepository(...)->getNumberPatient();
    $form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType, NULL_OR_OBJECT, [
       'text_data' => $data
    ]);
    ...
}
```

MyFormType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $data = $options['text_data'];

    $builder
        ->add('regCode', 'text', ['data' => $data])
        ...
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(['text_data' => null]);
}
```

- Another way, declare your form type as a service, inject the entity manager:

example:

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    // use it like $this->entityManager->...
}
```

- another way, pass the entityManager to form like 1-option, then get by `$options` array, like this `$entityManager = $options['entityManager']`, or you can even pass the entityManager to constructor.. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976226/symfony2-how-call-the-repository-of-an-entity-in-the-formtype/26976628#26976628) you can see it..

Comment: would u like me to send u via email? i did documented this problem in word office with picture

Comment: @enhaka you can upload it to the Dropbox and paste the link here.

Comment: @enhaka By the 2nd way, you're setting an argument in __constructor, but you're not passing the entityManager to it, which it requires, do it like this: `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); $form->createForm(new PatientType($em), DATA)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80200/discussion-between-enhaka-and-xurshid29).

Comment: @enhaka Sorry, I didn't see you wrote me a message.