# How to pass arguments to Datatransformer when using a custom field type

Tags: symfony

I need to transform a user name to a user entity, and I'm using this transformation in many form,every form need some specific test to the returned user entity.
In the registration form a user can enter a referral code (user name) or leave this empty, the referral code must have the role ROLE_PARTNER.
In the dashboard a partner can append some user to his account: in this case the user name can't be empty, the user must have the role ROLE_CLIENT and the partner can't enter his own user name 
this is my data transformer class

```
class UserToNameTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $om;
    private $role;
    private $acceptEmpty;
    private $logged;
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $om,$role,$acceptEmpty,$logged)
    {
        $this->om = $om;
        $this->role=$role;
        $this->acceptEmpty=$acceptEmpty;
        $this->logged=$logged;
    }
    public function transform($user)
    {
        if (null === $user) {
            return "";
        }

        return $user->getUsername();
    }
    public function reverseTransform($username)
    {
        if (!$username) {
            if ($this->acceptEmpty)
            return null;
            else 
                throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                        'user name can\'t be empty!'
                        ));

        }

        $user = $this->om
        ->getRepository('FMFmBundle:User')
        ->findOneBy(array('username' => $username))
        ;
        if (null === $user) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                    'user with user name "%s" not found!',
                    $username
                    ));
        }
        else if (!$user->hasRole($this->role)){
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                    'user name "%s" is not valid',
                    $username
                    ));
        }
        else if($this->logged==true){
            $activeUser=$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
            if($user===$activeUser)
                throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                        'you can\'t enter you user name'
                        ));
        }
        else
            return $user;
    }
}
```

Form type
this form work fine because I'm not using the custom field

```
class ActivatePartnerType extends AbstractType
{

    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('user','text', array(
                'invalid_message' => 'That is not a valid username',
                'label' => 'Partner Username :',
            ))
            ->add('next','submit')
        ;
        $builder->get('user')
            ->addModelTransformer(new UserToNameTransformer($this->entityManager,'ROLE_PARTNER',false,true));
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'fm_fmbundle_activate_partner';
    }
}
```

The custom field type

```
class UserSelectorType extends AbstractType
    {
        private $entityManager;

        public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
        {
            $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        }

        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $transformer = new UserToNameTransformer($this->entityManager,**{others parametres}**);
            $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
        }

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                    'invalid_message' => 'The selected user does not exist'
            ));
        }

        public function getParent()
        {
            return 'text';
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'user_selector';
        }
    }
```

the custom field service

```
FmarketUserSelector:
            class: FM\FmBundle\Form\UserSelectorType
            arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
            tags:
                - { name: form.type, alias: user_selector }
```

the form type

```
class ActivatePartnerType extends AbstractType
{

    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('user','user_selector')
            ->add('next','submit')
        ;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'fm_fmbundle_activate_partner';
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  You ask how to pass in parameters, but then you have a place holder exactly where you would do so.   Is your question instead "how do I get these values so I can pass them in as parameters?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, is how I use the $options array

```
class UserSelectorType extends AbstractType
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $transformer = new UserToNameTransformer($this->entityManager,$options['role'],$options['accept_empty'],$options['logged']);
        $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'invalid_message' => 'The selected user does not exist',
                'role'=>'ROLE_PARTNER',
                'accept_empty'=>true,
                'logged'=>false
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_selector';
    }
}
```

In the form type

```
$builder->add('referral','user_selector',array(
                    'role'=>'ROLE_PARTNER',
                    'accept_empty'=>false,
                    'logged'=>false
            ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this pages:

- [Introduction to Parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html)
- [Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)

In your case, it would look like this:

```
FmarketUserSelector:
    class: FM\FmBundle\Form\UserSelectorType
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "ROLE_PARTNER", false, true]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: user_selector }
```

but looks like, you're passing dynamic values to your form type, that's why this doesn't suit your needs I think..

In your case you can call your form type as a regular class call, like this:

```
...

$builder
    ->add('user', new UserSelectorType(ARG1, ARG2, ...))
    ->add('next','submit')
;

...
```

may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744798/symfony2-how-to-call-functions-in-repository-class-from-type/30748427#30748427) answer can also help you a bit..

Comment: Thanks for the code and the link,I used your solution and it work fine.
the link give me the idea of using the $options array, and i tried it,it work fine .

Comment: your solution is not using the service declaration so it's not useful in my case at that time cause now I'm using constraint validation instead of arguments.